# Confusion about django app's name

Tags: python, django

I learned Django following django book and the document. In the django book exmaple, the project is called mysite and there's an app called book inside this project. So in this case, the app is called "book". I've no problem with it.

My confusion arises in front of reusable apps. Reusable apps usually reside outside the project. For example, django-registration only has an independent folder "registration". So what's its app name? "Registration", right?

If that's the case, isn't there some inconsistency regarding the app naming? In the first case, app name seems to be a folder name (or sub package name) under the project while in the 2nd case, the app name is the top package name.

I know most of you will say "Why are you obssessed with app name? Just make sure the package structure is correct and django can run without problems." Yes, in most case, app name is nothing but a name. Except in one occasion: specify AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE. As the document explains,

> To indicate that this model is the
>   user profile model for a given site,
>   fill in the setting
>   AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE with a string
>   consisting of the following items,
>   separated by a dot:
>
> 1. The name of the application (case
>      sensitive) in which the user profile
>      model is defined (in other words, the
>      name which was passed to manage.py
>      startapp to create the application).
> 2. The name of the model (not case
>      sensitive) class.

If I have a model as a user profile in a resuable package, I have to know the app name to correctly specify AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE.

Does django use certain path searching order to decide the app name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the app is the name of the directory, capitalization and all, unless you go to the extra work to change the name in the appropriate `__init__.py` file. Django apps are, after all, just Python modules, and all the same rules apply.

If you ever see an app or module name with different capitalization or other modifications, that doesn't reflect the actual app or module name. Instead, what you're seeing is the result of some "pretty-printing" that the Django admin app is known to do in some cases. This is for display only.

Comment: I've playing with Django for a while. I think I know the answer now. App name is the leaf package name where your modules reside. So for a package like "a.b.c", c is the app name.

Answer (score 1):

> My confusion arises in front of reusable apps. Reusable apps usually reside outside the project. For example, django-registration only has an independent folder "registration". So what's its app name? "Registration", right?

`django-registration` is the project name. The application name is `registration`:

- in application list you are using the application name only: `registration`
- in other places you will use `import registration`

> If that's the case, isn't there some inconsistency regarding the app naming? In the first case, app name seems to be a folder name (or sub package name) under the project while in the 2nd case, the app name is the top package name.

Think of the project as a simple collection of applications: you could store the apps as subfolders, or place them in a separate folder (that must be included in PYTHONPATH). In both cases the application name is the same.

**Update**

`manage.py` adds to the PYTHONPATH both the current folder (so you could use `import app.module`) and the parent folder (so you can use `project.settings` and `project.urls`).
So, if you can configure Pydev to add the project folder to the PYTHONPATH, then you could import the apps as `app.module`, independent of the project name.

Comment: But the porject folder is also a package. If the apps reside under it, I have to do importing like "project.app.module", which I think is ungraceful since an app has no reason to know the project name. So I like to place apps on the top package. But Pydev gives me no option but the subfolder under the project. Have to do some manual work working with Pydev :(.

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy and app as a standalone package, it is just another Python package, which happens to implement Django views, templates, template tags, etc. Therefore, Django's search path is the Python search path itself. This is why people say "Just make sure the package structure is correct and django can run without problems."

Obviously, if the package name conflicts with someone else's package, you are going to get problems...

Answer (score 0):

An app name is just the name of the Python module. Nothing more.

A python module name is the case name of the root folder of the module, that must contains an **init**.py file.

If you want to know what this name is, go to your site-packages folder and look for your module.